# pass value to the template if contains in html angular

Tags: html, angular

I'm stuck on an issue.

I've a dropdown

```
<id-select [value]="id" [title]="'Select ID'" [first_value]="'Select ID'"
                     (onValueChanged)="idChanged($event)"></id-select>
```

How could I render a html based on the `value`?
For example

If the `value` is 1, then `<strong>Content is visible<strong>`

if the `value` is 2, then `<strong>Content is not visible<strong>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the structural directive `*ngIf`.

```
<strong *ngIf="id === 1">Content is visible</strong>
```

If the id is one, the `strong` element will be rendered and for any other value it won't be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *ngIf with the id binding and you can use *ngSwitch with the id binding, I recommend to use *ngSwitch if you have multiple of values.
You can read about both of them right here: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngif-and-ngswitch/